# Milliseconds delay after unlocking phone causes unresponsiveness

Tags: ios, ui, screen-lock, iphone, animation

Does anyone realise a delay after unlocking the iPhone screen on iOS7 ? You cannot swipe left or right until the animation finishes at 100%, rendering the phone unresponsive till then.

This is kind of annoying, albeit a small issue, but it affects the whole snappy experience I'm having with iOS7.

Any fix for this ? I expected it to be fixed by iOS 7.0.3 update, but it isn't.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have to just wait for the animation to finish.

By turning on 'Reduce Motion' you get another animation, which looks like it is a bit faster. But this function changes the whole feeling from iOS 7. You can find it at General - Accessibility -  Reduce Motion.